# Filter Remote Method in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I have created a remote method in loopback

```
  XXX.remoteMethod('getAllGlobalFilters', {
    'description': 'List of all GlobalFilters',
    'http': {
      'path': '/getAllGlobalFilters',
      'verb': 'get'
    },
    'accepts': [
      {'arg': 'filter', 'type': 'object', 'http': {'source': 'query'}}
    ],
    'returns': {'arg': 'allGlobalFilters', 'type': 'array'}
  });


  XXX.getAllGlobalFilters = function(arg, callback) {
    console.log(arg);
    rtbSspPubFilter.find({
      where: {
        type: 15
      },
      include: [{relation: 'XXX'}]
    }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      return callback(null, data);
    });
  };
};
```

I am able to use find and the remote method is working fine but i am not able to use the regular expression like filtering in the remote method how do i access loop back default filters for the same.

[image]

I want to use the json like filters that is available for native loopback models. like the image above

Comment: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html as you can read here the filter method isn't one of the properties of the remote method so you can  include the filter in your path like `/getAllGlobalFilters?filter[something]=something&filter[limit]=3`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as good practice in your remote function, instead of using `arg` use the name you defined in your remote method, which is `filter`. That way, when you'd have more than one properties defined, it will be less confusing.

But, in your issue, you just have to pass a string, then parse it into a JSON object in your function, like the following:

```
   XXX.remoteMethod('getAllGlobalFilters',
         {
            'accepts': [{'arg': 'filter','type': 'string'}],
           'http': {
               'path': '/getAllGlobalFilters',
               'verb': 'get'
             },
            'returns': {'arg': 'allGlobalFilters', 'type': 'array'}
         });

   XXX.getAllGlobalFilters = function(filter, callback) {
       filter = JSON.parse(filter);
       rtbSspPubFilter.find(filter, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            return callback(err);
          }
          return callback(null, data);
        });
   };
```

Hope this helps!